# How do I get a directory to "point" towards the right bucket when making my own extendable hashing project?

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I've read up on the wiki page on creating a extendable hashtable [Extendable Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extendible_hashing). And now i'm trying to implement that into a program to better understand it but I can't figure out how to actually point the directories towards the buckets.

Directory class:

```
int GlobalDepth = 1;
int directories[];

public Directory() {
    int temp = (int)Math.pow(2, GlobalDepth);

    loadDirectories(temp);

}

public void loadDirectories(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        String BinaryKey = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        String tempKey = BinaryKey.substring(0, this.GlobalDepth); // LSB
        int depthKey = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(tempKey);

        this.directories[i] = depthKey;

    }

}

public void increaseGlobalDepth() {
    this.GlobalDepth ++;

    loadDirectories((int)(Math.pow(2, this.GlobalDepth))); // This method might throw an error because i think im changing the array size illegally and should instead create a temp array and copy/equal that array to this.directories

}
```

Bucket class:

```
private SomeObject[] item; // Class I'm using to hold all the information of something
private int Key, MaxBucketsize, LocalDepth = 1;
//Bucket next;

public Bucket() {

}

public Bucket(int BucketSize) {
    this.item = new SomeObject[BucketSize]; // Initalises the number of items held in the bucket
    this.MaxBucketsize = BucketSize; // Stores the max number of items that can be held in the bucket

}


public SomeObject[] getObjects() {
    return this.item;

}

public boolean addObjects(int key, SomeObject item) {
    boolean inserted = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.MaxBucketsize; i ++) {
        if (this.item[i] == null) { // only inserts if there is an empty spot in the bucket
            this.item[i] = item;
            this.item[i].setKey(key);

            inserted = true;

            break;

        }

    }

    return inserted;

}
```

After doing all this, I'm not sure how to now link the 2 together like in the wiki page.

Comment: Yeah how can i send it to you?